# Stem is giving the "Unable to connect to port 9051" error

Tags: python, python-2.7, tor, stem

I tried [this](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html) example:

```
import getpass
import sys

import stem
import stem.connection

from stem.control import Controller

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
    controller = Controller.from_port()
  except stem.SocketError as exc:
    print("Unable to connect to tor on port 9051: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

  try:
    controller.authenticate()
  except stem.connection.MissingPassword:
    pw = getpass.getpass("Controller password: ")

    try:
      controller.authenticate(password = pw)
    except stem.connection.PasswordAuthFailed:
      print("Unable to authenticate, password is incorrect")
      sys.exit(1)
  except stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure as exc:
    print("Unable to authenticate: %s" % exc)
    sys.exit(1)

  print("Tor is running version %s" % controller.get_version())
  controller.close()
```

on Stem to check how Tor's controller works. But its giving me the error:

> Unable to connect to port 9051 ([Errno 111] Connection refused)

I have set the ControlPort to 9051 in the torrc file inside /etc/tor/ but am still getting the same error. Could anyone please help?
(I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on VirtualBox)

EDIT: Also running tor --controlport 9051 on the terminal gives the error:

```
Feb 29 17:50:17.842 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.27 (git-412e3f7dc9c6c01a) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.21-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1f.
Feb 29 17:50:17.842 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Feb 29 17:50:17.842 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Feb 29 17:50:17.854 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Feb 29 17:50:17.854 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Feb 29 17:50:17.854 [notice] Opening Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Feb 29 17:50:17.854 [notice] Closing partially-constructed Control listener on 127.0.0.1:9051
Feb 29 17:50:17.854 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Feb 29 17:50:17.854 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.
```

but when I run

> ps

there is no instance of tor running.
EDIT 2: I tried the command `sudo killall tor` and then checked it with `sudo /etc/init.d/tor status`and now its giving an authentication error:

```
 File "circuitPage.py", line 82, in printCircuitInfo
    controller.authenticate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/control.py", line 991, in authenticate
    stem.connection.authenticate(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/stem/connection.py", line 520, in authenticate
    raise AuthenticationFailure('socket connection failed (%s)' % exc)
stem.connection.AuthenticationFailure: socket connection failed ([Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

find `ControlPort 9051` in `/etc/tor/torrc` config file then uncomment the line.
then reset tor by:
`sudo service tor restart`
now you can connect to port 9051