# TorGo Connect to Tor ControlPort Running In Docker Compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose, tor

I have a docker-compose file which runs a tor node and I also have a simple Go script which attempts to use [torgo](https://github.com/wybiral/torgo) to connect to said tor node.

I run the docker-compose and then I run a simple curl command to check that the SOCKS5 proxy is working, all is fine:

```
$ curl --socks5 127.0.0.1:9050 https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
{"IsTor":true,"IP":"185.83.214.69"}
```

But if I run my Go script to try and connect with port `9051` to get a controller instance, every attempt fails with error `EOF`.

I've also tried connecting via `telnet` and receive errors there as well:

```sh
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 9051
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I've tried a number of different things at this point, too many to recall right now but things including, different docker images, mounting my own `torrc` config with auth enabled and various other parameters, etc. Nothing is working...

What am I missing? How can I connect to the `ControlPort`?

**docker-compose**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  torproxy:
    restart: always
    image: dperson/torproxy:latest
    ports:
      - "9050:9050" # Tor proxy
      - "9051:9051" # Tor control port
      - "8118:8118" # Privoxy
```

**main.go**

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/wybiral/torgo"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    addr := "127.0.0.1:9051"
    c, err := torgo.NewController(addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to create tor controller: %s", err)
    }
    log.Println(c)
}
```

Comment: It takes time for the node to connect and setup its network routes. It might just be you need to implement a retry strategy to give it the required time before giving it up. https://github.com/dperson/torproxy#exposing-the-port

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to connect to the Docker tor instance by binding the ControlPort to `0.0.0.0:9051` in torrc, rather than the default.

**torrc default**

```
ControlPort 9051
```

**torrc updated**

```
ControlPort 0.0.0.0:9051
```

This makes the control port accessible from outside the container.

This SO post got me to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58138489/5750392